# How to remove the warning of repeated words in Pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

I have disabled typos but I still have inspection warnings like below in PyCharm (*"typo: you repeated a word"*). How can I get rid of them without manually ignoring them every time? In my field I have repeated words (genes) which aren't mistakes.

An example that shows this problem:

```
# test test
```

[image]

---

- Python 3.10.2
- Pycharm 2021.3
- Windows 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the trick. It was actually because of the [grammar inspection](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/grammar.html), and not the [typo inspection](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/spellchecking.html) that you need to uncheck.